# (VHDL) Arithmetical operations on IEEE 754 coded floating point values stored as std_logic_vectors

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

I need to do operations on IEEE 754 floating point numbers stored as `std_logic_vector` signals.

e.g.:

```
signal a, b, ans : std_logic_vector( 63 downto 0 );
..
ans <= std_logic_vector(to_float(a) + to_float(b));
```

How can I do that? (I suppose I need to define the number of bits somewhere during the conversion?) 
edit: the code is synthesizable but I get warnings. Code:

```
variable tempfloat1, tempfloat2, tempfloat3 : float32;
..
tempfloat1 := to_float(s_do_ssc2wb, exponent_width => 8, fraction_width => 23 );
tempfloat2 := to_float(s_do_wb2ssc, exponent_width => 8, fraction_width => 23 );
tempfloat3 := tempfloat1 + tempfloat2;
```

Warnings:

```
 "float_pkg_c.vhdl" line 1515: VHDL Assertion Statement with non constant condition is ignored.
    "float_pkg_c.vhdl" line 1600: Index value(s) does not match array range, simulation mismatch.
```

I wonder whats the right syntax for it... the "add" function doesn't accept the arguments like in the example in the user's guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For VHDL 2008, use the built-in float_pkg which provides the float type which is convertable to and from std_logic_vector. For earlier versions of VHDL, you can use the original, pre-standard version of these same packages from http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/index.html .

When using float types, they work very straightforwardly, similar to unsigned types: you can do arithmetic on them, resize them, etc.

Comment: But still, it is always worth investigatin whether fixed-point logic won't do, because floating-point arithmetic results in much bigger and slower designs. In the FAQ on the site you mention, it says that an overhead of 3x is to be expected... I would hazard a guess that this is a lower bound.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded needed files from that page and added them to a library like this: library IEEE_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.float_pkg.all; and now I use to_float function like in the question. It is synthesizable but I will try to simulate it to make sure it works correct.

Comment: there is also a very good example in [this document](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Float_ug.pdf) on page 5.

Comment: now I changed my design a little bit, but not the calculation statement. the XST now throws a warning: "WARNING:Xst:1610 - "D:/../float_pkg_c.vhdl" line 6139: Width mismatch. <result806<10:0>> has a width of 11 bits but assigned expression is 8-bit wide." but when you look in the file at that line, its `result (exponent_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '1');  -- Exponent all "1"`

Comment: @MaxKrug sounds like you are missing a `resize` call somewhere in your code.

Comment: but what should be resized? when I have 64 bit slv's and then I convert them to_float(arg, 11, 52); and do calcs. I dont wanna resize them to single precision. But I still get warnings even when handling with single precision numbers. I will post the code in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used the floating point IP cores, generated with the IP core generator in the ISE. The Floating point packages linked above were actually worthless since the synthesis took like an hour and the maximum frequency was only ~6 MHZ on a Spartan3. With IP cores: 40 MHz and 3-5 minutes synthesis time.